# Induced map on jacobians of curves of genus one

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field and consider two genus-one curves $C,C^{\prime}$ (probably without $K$-points). Let $f:C\to C^{\prime} $ be a morphism defined over $K$. Do I understand correctly that if we take the induced map on jacobians $J(C^{\prime})\to J ( C)$ and than consider its dual $J ( C)\to J(C^{\prime})$ we obtain an isogeny of elliptic curves over $K$ isomorphic to $f$ over $\overline{K}$?

Comment: For an elliptic curve $C,C'$ over $K$ constructing $J(C)$, the isomorphism $C\to J(C)$ over $L$ containing a point and the dual of an isogeny $J(C')\to J(C)$ is for sure interesting, the dual of the dual isogeny $J(C')\to J(C)$ should be a bit obvious, given by $f$ up to some isomorphisms over $L$.

Comment: So, you think my statement is true?